# Which non-parametric test can I use for binary response?

Tags: statistical-significance, binary-data

I have two groups of respondents - Group A & Group B with 10 samples each. During an interview they were asked a question to which the answer is yes or no (recorded as 1 and 0). I wanted to check if there is statistically significant difference between Group A and B as far as that particular question is concerned. Which test statistic would be the best for this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: erm... is there a problem with considering a parametric test? In particular is there something that would make you discount treating your 0's and 1's as Bernoulli? (with parameters $p_A$ and $p_B$ under the alternative) Is there likely within sample dependence? Is there any pairing or are A and B independent samples? Did you have any concept (before collecting the data) what general region the overall proportion of 'yes' might be? (say whether it would be maybe 10% or 90% or instead something more in the middle...)

Comment: @Glen_b mentions some very important aspects influencing the appropriateness of most available tests. And it takes some more information from the OP to recommend a specific one. That said, if you really need a non-parametric test for proportions, you might want to consider a permutation test.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Glen and IWS for your valuable comments. I have just 28 samples and thats why I thought of using a non-parametric test. Within sample dependence is unlikely in this case. The prop of 1s is around 0.6 and the prop of 0s is around 0.4.

Comment: If you have 28 "samples" and "Group A & Group B with 10 samples each" ... what happened to the other eight??